# What's wrong with this wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

Something is wrong with the wiring in my shed, I think. I'm pretty sure that it's been wrong since the previous occupants lived here, and maybe even earlier than that.

When I moved in there was clear evidence of scorching in the shed - apparently something had melted and caught fire. I'm sure it was a rather exciting time. I replaced the damaged wiring and the receptacles, but when we were trying to wire things up correctly we could not figure out the correct order of the wires. It doesn't help that they're all gray wires. We spend a lot of time scratching our heads and puzzling, and then I realized that at *most* we had 6 different combinations, so we tried each paring and finally figured out that at least one of them was ground, but we still couldn't figure out which was hot and which was neutral. So we just wired things up and the only thing I plugged in was an incandescent lightbulb.

Recently I've thought to revisit the shed wiring and have discovered something that seems rather strange. Between ground and one side, I'm reading ~240v, and ground and the other side I'm getting ~120v.

I'm not sure what they're supposed to read, but on another outlet between ground and neutral I don't get any reading, and ground and hot I get 120v.

## 120v Between Hot and Ground

[image: 120v - good ol' American current]

## 240v Between Neutral and Ground

[image: Enough for a 240 wat. Wat is this even?]

## My Dummy Light is Confused, Too

[image: dummy light is all lit up!]

You may not be able to see the label clear enough, but my dummy light has all three lights on - but that doesn't correspond to *any* of the options on the label.

So I'm terribly confused as to what's going on here. How would I find and fix the issue here? I'm assuming it's probably in my circuit box - I took it off once before, so I know where it is and a little about it. I don't have the option to shut off the mains electricity to the house, so if I *were* to undertake such a fix, what safety precautions should I take? (If the outlets don't make it clear enough, I'm in the United States)

## Inside My Breaker Box

[image: inside my breaker box]

On the right side you can see three wires coming in through the back of the box: they go up to the 20A circuit breaker on the right side and to the ground rail - those are the wires that go out to the shed.

Comment: What's the reading between hot and neutral on the culprit outlet?

Comment: First you need to answer @ThreePhaseEel question. Then kill all power to the shed. Then open up the receptacle and get us a picture of how it is wired. Is that a 12/3 feeding into your receptacle? And how many breakers did you have to turn off before killing all power to the shed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I was worried about plugging my meter into it. The *last* time I did it literally fried the probes - about 1/8"-1/4" of the tips of the probes vaporized. I don't remember if the meter survived. If I can find it I'll take some photos. I didn't try hot and neutral again because I thought I did something wrong the last time. It was a cheap HF meter, but I did have the probe plugged into the high voltage slot.

Comment: What else does this breaker control?

Comment: Is there a sub panel in the shed?  What number is on the end of the handle for that double pole breaker feeding the shed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's it. The conduit you see coming up into the bottom of that outlet is directly on the other end of the wires coming into this breaker box.

Comment: @Tyson no sub panel - just goes directly to that outlet in the shed.

Comment: So you have heavy gauge black wires leaving the panel, from a double pole breaker, but in the shed outlet picture I see yellow 12 gauge Romex?

Comment: @Tyson those feed to the light switch and to a second outlet that's wired in... parallel, I think. The light switch is wired to a 3rd outlet in the ceiling.

Comment: Where's the main breaker in this panel of yours?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It doesn't have one. I'm not sure if they just didn't care when they put it in, or if the code was a bit more lax. I don't think I've seen *any* houses around here that have a main breaker (granted I've only seen like 2 or 3, but they've all been older homes).

Comment: @WayneWerner -- go find the dang thing then and get back to us (it might be hiding out by the meter?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel there isn't one at all - the pedastal is on the other side of my yard, from there to my meter is a long brand new wire with brand new conduit. The meter has no shut off, and from there it goes through the wall into this panel. Unless the shut-off is somewhere looking for a cask of Amantillado ;) :P

Comment: And the panel doesn't have a main breaker out of view beyond the top of your photo, either, I take it?

Comment: [Nope. No main breaker anywhere](https://goo.gl/photos/i939wztSHCmqvs7v9).

Comment: @WayneWerner -- can you post a new question asking what's going on with your panel please, with the photos of the panel inside and outside you have already + a photo of the panel label & a photo of the top inside of the panel? Either this is a real oddity (a split bus QO) or a *severe* Code violation (MLO panel improperly used as a main panel with no service disconnecting means)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel [done](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/117567/118)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As-wired, the three wires are Hot, Hot and Neutral. You do not have a ground wire, (unless this run is in metal conduit, in which case the metal conduit is the ground path.)

A 120V receptacle has 3 wires: Hot, Neutral and Ground. Your conceptual problem is you are trying to match 3 wires to 3 wires. And that will never work because those 3 wires have different functions.

### First, sort out the Ground question.

Look closely at the conduit carrying the wires. I assume it is conduit because I see 3 loose wires same color.  If indeed the conduit is all-metal, and continuous, and joints in good condition, then you have a ground *in the conduit" which should be accessible at the metal box attached to the conduit. It should have a hole tapped 10-32 that you can put a grounding screw into.

You might have an electrician **test** this believed-to-be-ground path to see if it can really carry a strong current flow. To be actually useful, it must be able to flow enough current to assure the circuit breaker trips.

If you do not have a viable ground path, or if you want "belt and suspenders", you can **retrofit a ground**: route a copper ground wire from the shed back to the house, via any legal method.  If it is indeed in conduit, you might be able to just fish (or even push!) the ground wire through.

The last option is to simply **leave it ungrounded**.  Toss out those NEMA 5 (3-prong) receptacles and buy NEMA 1 (2-prong) receptacles.  This will be allowed if the wiring is old enough to be grandfathered (i.e. was installed before grounds became law).  If you do this, I strongly recommend you replace the circuit breaker with a GFCI type.

*Here's what you can't do:* Grab some green tape and mark one of the hot wires as a ground. It is now illegal to remark a black wire (of this size) as a ground.  A ground must be green, green/yellow stripe, **or bare**.

### A local grounding rod is *no substitute*

If this were any more sophisticated, you would need a local grounding system (rods) at the shed.  You don't because this is a single (multi-wire) circuit into a single breaker.  Here's the point: **Do not use a grounding rod as a substitute for a ground wire**.  You need a ground wire back to the panel so that ground faults will trip the breaker.  A ground rod won't do that because *dirt is just dirt*, it is not a magical superconductor.  Dirt conducts electricity about as well as you'd expect, and it won't flow enough current (if it flows any at all) to give you a reliable breaker trip.

So don't even think about using a local grounding rod at the shed as a substitute for running a proper ground.  It is a nice add-on, though: what it does is give a very direct path for Mother Earth's electricity - lightning and static electricity - to get back to its source.

### Then sort out the Neutral

I see in the service panel where one of the black wires has white tape on it.  Similar to green tape, it is now illegal to re-mark a black wire (of this size) to be a neutral.  If the installation is old enough it may be grandfathered, and I would take the assumption that it is.   In that case, it's OK to use new tape to freshen the mark, as that one is falling off.

It's important the mark be intact on the other end of the wire too.  Freshen it there too.  It's vital not to get the wires mixed up.

### You have Hot-Hot-Neutral.  Use it that way.

What you have is called an Edison circuit or a multi-wire branch circuit.  This can give you 240V (hot-hot) or 120V (hot-neutral) or 120+240 (hot-neutral-hot) for dryers or subpanels which use both.

If you want a 240V circuit, use the two hot wires.  This could go into a NEMA 2 receptacle (or if you have a good ground you can wire, use NEMA 6).

If you want a 120V circuit, use *one of* the hot wires and the neutral.  Do not use the other hot wire.  Without a ground use a NEMA 1 receptacle, with ground use a NEMA 5 as in your picture.

If you want a 120+240V circuit, use *both* hots, and neutral, *and ground*.  If you have ground, use a NEMA 14 receptacle.  If you do not have ground, *do not install it.* 120+240 without ground kills people.

Comment: Ah! That explains a whole lot, actually. I bet the original owner (this house was built in the 70s) ran the wiring to his shed and had the NEMA-1 receptacles. Then I'm also guessing that the previous owner got rid of the 2-prong receptacles and tried to put in the 3-prongs (which were in the shed when I bought the place). I'm guessing he assumed that there was a ground, neutral and hot. Until he plugged in whatever he did that burnt the *mess* out of the previous receptacles, and several of the wires (which is why there's the yellow stuff in there now).

Comment: 240V would be useful to have out there if I decided to get a 240V welder. But what I really need to do here, then, is to get a green wire and push/pull it all the way through this conduit to/from my shed, hook it to the ground bus at the bottom of the panel, and then I can use *that* as ground in the shed?

Comment: Green or bare, but yeah, that'll work

Comment: Yes, you'd have to price the options but they sell an 8 AWG bare ground wire that would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

### Found: 1 240V boobytrap

Whoever wired this circut last left you with a boobytrap on your hands -- one of the black wires is landed to what appears to be a subpanel ground bus, and the other two wires land on the 20A *double pole* breaker on the right side of the panel.  Hence, the circuit is a 240V circuit -- you won't get right results no matter what you do with hooking the existing wires up to that receptacle, because it's a NEMA 5 receptacle and only meant for 120V service.

You'll need to re-run the ground wire with a green wire no matter what; other than that, you can replace the double pole breaker with a single pole and one of the other black wires with a white wire to get a 120V circuit, or put NEMA 6s and 240V LED or fluorescent fixtures in and keep your shed at 240VAC *provided* all your loads there can run on 240V.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I should run some real wires out there *anyway* - those wires are actually stranded, not solid, right? So would I run the green *and* the white wire to the ground bus? And then the (new) black wire to a 20A breaker? Could I just wire it up to one of the poles on that existing breaker?

Comment: Stranded wire in raceways (such as conduit) is A-OK -- as to reusing the existing breaker, it'd simply confuse the next bloke who has to work on it, though.  The green wire lands on ground and the white lands on *neutral* btw -- the panel you posted a photo of looks to be a subpanel, not a main panel.

Comment: The panel I posted is where the mains comes into the house - it's the only thing I've got. This house was built in the 1970s, so maybe it's just the age? What's the difference between neutral and ground? I see a bunch of other white wires connected to both of the bars down there.

Comment: @WayneWerner: Technically, this is a fairly normal 3-wire "Edison" circuit with a shared neutral (grounded conductor) and no grounding conductor. I can't see what the amps rating is on that 2-pole breaker, but the wires look like they're #12, and if the breaker is no larger than 20A, you could connect just one hot and the neutral to that receptacle and have a normal 20A, 120V receptacle. You could wire the other hot through to the lights and they're effectively on their own circuit, etc. You should pull a grounding wire, and the neutral should be marked a different color.

Comment: @Craig I try to discourage people from using the term "grounded conductor".  I know the NFPA lawyers like it because it's a precise legal term, but it's super confusing to everyone else, and contradicts the NEC itself.  In fact, neutral is not *and should not be* grounded (it typically floats millivolts above ground, the point being to  be *near* ground for safety)... meanwhile everywhere else in NEC, ground is treated as *not* a conductor *at all*.  The colloquial names are, in these cases, more informative.

Comment: @Craig that's a 30A breaker - does that mean I should replace the one 30A with two 20A single pole breaker?

Comment: @Harper I don't disagree at all that it can be confusing (grounded vs grounding). I tend to include the technical terms in conjunction with the colloquial for educational purposes and to try to be precise, e.g. The grounded (neutral) conductor or the neutral (grounded) conductor. The neutral *is* physically grounded at the transformer, though, by design, and in the main panel the neutral and grounding wires are electrically bonded, so the neutral is by definition and practice the grounded conductor, while the hot conductors are not grounded.

Comment: The further distinction being that the neutral is a potentially dangerous conductor, carrying precisely as much current as the "hot" conductors.

Comment: @WayneWerner: If the wire is #12 AWG, then the breaker can't be any bigger than 20A. In that case, you could replace it with a 2-pole 20A breaker and have 2 20A circuits, like I was talking about, or you could use one 20A breaker and cap one of the hot wires so that you only have one circuit. If the wire is #10, then the breaker is okay for the wiring, but if your receptacle and/or light fixtures aren't rated for 30A passthrough, you would have to pigtail everything or just replace the breaker for safety.

Comment: @Craig "educational purposes" who are you teaching and what are you teaching them? Is this a thing worth teaching, how does it help them?   I concluded that learning the legal term is about as useful as knowing the capital of Dagestan.

Comment: I'm saying the neutral actually is literally, physically grounded. It literally is the grounded conductor. Neutral is a slang term. Albeit a pervasive one.  :)

Comment: Then why run three wires?   The problem is that people *already* have a tendency to consider neutral and ground to be functionally the same thing and that it's ok to use one when you need the other.  We constantly labor to convince them otherwise.  That terminology just digs the hole deeper.  And it's NOT grounded, hence separate wires, at any location but one.

Comment: So... I know that I need to have one wire hooked up to the breaker, and one wire hooked up to the ground bus. Where does the 3rd wire get hooked up to?

Comment: @WayneWerner The answer is it's a mess.  You need a neutral (to the neutral bus) and a ground (to the ground bus) but you can't relabel those black wires as either a neutral or ground.  Generally neutrals go to the neutral bus and grounds to the ground bus.  As Craig and I are discussing, *in the main panel only* that is the same.

Comment: @Harper: because that's how you get 120V circuits... ;-)   **WayneWerner**: Harper is absolutely correct (just backing him up). Neutral and grounding wires are required to be electrically bonded in the main service panel, but *only* in the main service panel. Everyplace downstream including in any outlets and any subpanels, the grounding and neutral wires must be kept isolated from each other. They are NOT equivalent.

Comment: You should either pull the black-colored neutral wire out and replace it with a white one, plus a ground, which would give you two 120V circuits (each hot black wire is a 120V circuit, sharing the neutral). **OR** it is simpler to understand if you just pull two black wires out and run one white and one grounding wire, which will leave you with a single 120V grounded circuit. Right now it's a confusing mess and you'll fry equipment or start a fire, or both, plugging it into a 240V circuit.

Comment: I didn't realize it, but @Harper left a very solid answer before I made these comments.

Answer (score 3):

**That's severely wrong.**

It appears you have two wires connected as hot wires that are connected to the neutral and ground of that receptacle. Hence the 248 volt reading.

Then the hot terminal on the receptacle is connected to either the ground or the neutral at the panel giving you 123 volts between the hot wire connected to the ground terminal of the receptacle and the wire connected to the hot terminal on the receptacle.

Re-check your wiring and verify each wire individually from the panel. Make sure they are terminated where they should be.

**Do NOT plug anything into this receptacle to test it until you straighten this out.**

If you have a difficult time with this call a reputable electrical contractor to correct this issue before something burns down or someone is hurt.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: Yeah -- that's what I'm suspecting -- hopefully the OP can get us a hot/neutral reading that will most likely verify this theory.

Comment: I've added a photo to my post of the inside of my panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just looking at the outlet and meter readings it appears the outlet hot = neutral, outlet ground = hot, outlet neutral = hot.  Getting 120v between outlet hot and outlet ground and 240v between outlet neutral and outlet ground would tell me that it should be 120v between outlet neutral and outlet hot.  Is that correct?